# find base href of a given url

Tags: php, web-crawler, baseline

I'm modifying a simple php crawler script.

one of the modules it uses is a converter of relative urls into absolute urls.

For this, I need to find a way to determine the base href of a given url. Otherwise I end up with a bunch of wrongly converted links.

I need a simple function to check if an url has a base href tag, and if yes, return it.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean with "baseline url tag"? :?

Comment: thank you. i edited the original post. i meant 'base href'

Answer (score 0):

[`parse_url()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) splits up a URL into its parts. You can get what you need from that.

Comment: Actually it doesn't. pathinfo is for splitting up a filepath

Comment: D'oh, I meant parse_url! Fixed.

Comment: @Griffin he's talking about a web crawler, so I imagine he reads for example a page on `http://host/products/foobar.html`, and in there are URL's (to other pages or images) like `images/foobar.jpg`. When combined, this will become the URL `http://host/products/images/foobar.jpg`, which is not right, since the image is in `http://host/images/foobar.jpg`. So somewhere on the `foobar.html` page, there is a `<base href="http://host/">` tag. He wants to read that, to determine all relative URL's.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you exactly mean but [parse_url](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) will give you a lot of information such as the hostname, the querystring, etc.

If I understand you correctly you wan't to know if there is a http in your url. The scheme part of the information parse_url returns is your friend here. If scheme is empty or something different then http, you know that there was no http in your URL.

Inside the crawler you start crawling a specific page and you parse that HTML if I understand your question correct. Simply construct the base URL (without paths) from the information parse_url gives you and I don't see any problems.

Answer (score 0):

> I need a simple function to check if an url has a base href tag, and if yes, return it.

A URL cannot have a base href tag, since that is an HTML tag. It might be defined in the HTML that you retreive from that URL. How to read that can be found [at this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-to-parse-and-process-html-with-php).

Comment: this code is what i'm using as the reference point. how do i the base href using the same process?

Comment: @UnoMeinAme: what code are you talking about? Can you update your question?